# How to automatically turn off a Fan after a fixed amount of time?

Tags: timer, switching, fan, home-automation

I have an exhaust fan in my bathroom (used for removing the steam generated by a hot bath).

Currently, it can be turned on and off by a regular switch.

**My goal**: Exhaust fan should automatically turn-off 5 minutes after it is turned on.

Comment: Uhm, most domestic exhaust fans already have this feature built-in?

Comment: The fan is AC, yes? If you have DC available, you can use either a DC relay or else an AC relay with a MOC30x3 IC. If you only have AC available at the site, then it may be more convenient to get a simple HLK-PM01 or similar so that you have DC and then develop the timer from there.

Comment: The other, perhaps preferred, way is to add a humidity sensor, either replacing the wall switch or added at the fan. This way, it turns on and off automatically.

Comment: Switches that do exactly what you want are inexpensive and available in hardware stores.

Comment: Use a [Timer Switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Woods-15-Amp-5-10-15-30-Minute-In-Wall-Countdown-Digital-Timer-Switch-White-59007WD/203638983?mtc=Shopping-B-F_D27E-G-D27E-27_31_CONTROL-NA-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-CONTROL_Nondoorbells&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D27E-G-D27E-27_31_CONTROL-NA-NA-Feed-PLA-NA-NA-CONTROL_Nondoorbells-71700000052998923-58700005105045162-92700050457564096&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7ZL6BRCmARIsAH6XFDKy0JyuS-6Di2yZ8FQTcPsENX8LSYBrPLZWh3T3DImSKDWVahNB1qAaAuN9EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: @jeroen define most and domestic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the existing switch with a UL-rated timer switch. Anything else will run the risk of invalidating your fire insurance.

[image: timer switch]

Answer (score 2):

Such a timer can be purchased. The switch starts the fan (AC) and runs for a few minutes after switching off. The fan is switched by a small triac and the timing is done by a CMOS gate. Its supply voltage (12V) is from mains voltage through a capacitor and a Zener.
[image: vent1]

[image: vent]

[image: vent3]

(Made in Italy)

Answer (score 1):

The requirement will be readily met by an off-the-shelf 'Toilet Exhaust Fan Timer'.

Nonetheless, the following schematic, using a 555 monostable, a transistor and an electromagnetic relay, is presented for academics' sake.

[image]

The circuit is an adaptation of this power off delay circuit published in Seekic.com.

http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Control_Circuit/Power_OFF_Delay_Circuits.html

It's an example of a true off-delay timer.

After the switch is turned on the output would be energized. Subsequent turning-off of the switch would signal the commencement of the delay time, at the end of which the output would be de-energized.

The values of 'R' and 'C' would decide the off-delay time.

Comment: It is a good idea to expand on comments like provide a circuit diagram, care to elaborate?

Comment: 555 timer and 5 minutes is not normally a viable combination.

Comment: Homemade circuit and permanent building wiring is not normally a viable combination (building code violation).

Comment: The answer has been edited thanks to all the comments.